# Is there any way to split the text file data using delimiters ans show it in textboxes?

Tags: c#, split, filestream

Here is the original data saved in text file

```
zeeshan
adnan
shams
jawaid
```

and I want this data in separate 4 textboxes by searching the first name.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
    sr.ReadLine();
    var textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt");

    foreach (var Line in textLines)
    {
        // (str, "\n\\s*")
        //string[] dataArray = Regex.Split('n');
        string[] dataArray = Line.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dataArray[0].CompareTo(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        if (dataArray[0] == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            textBox1.Text = (dataArray[0]);
            textBox2.Text = (dataArray[1]);
            textBox3.Text = (dataArray[2]);
            textBox4.Text = (dataArray[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that when I press the button it shows an exception at index[1].

Error is:

> "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside of your `foreach` loop.  What you probably want is to use a different delimiter or to move the entire loop body to the outside.  As it is the exception is working as it should.

Comment: You get "Index was outside the bounds of the array." because your dataArray contains just 1 element and you are referencing 1, 2, 3rd element also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

```
// FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
// StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
// sr.ReadLine();
// Above three lines are redundant, because you read all of the text inside next line (ReadAllLines)
var textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt");

// This foreach loop is wrong, since textLines already is array of lines from text file (each element is already single line without Environment.NewLine characters)
/*foreach (var Line in textLines)
{
    // (str, "\n\\s*")
    //string[] dataArray = Regex.Split('n');
    string[] dataArray = Line.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // This CompareTo is redundant also, since you are not using its result
    dataArray[0].CompareTo(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    if (dataArray[0] == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        textBox1.Text = (dataArray[0]);
        textBox2.Text = (dataArray[1]);
        textBox3.Text = (dataArray[2]);
        textBox4.Text = (dataArray[3]);
    }
}*/

// Instead of foreachloop above, you just need to put values inside textboxes:
if (textLines[0] == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
{
    textBox1.Text = (textLines[0]);
    textBox2.Text = (textLines[1]);
    textBox3.Text = (textLines[2]);
    textBox4.Text = (textLines[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllLines(...)` returns a string for each "new line".  That means there will be no `System.Environment.NewLine` in each line.  Which correctly causes an "index out of range" exception when you try to access the line parts.

```
// I'll walk you though your code...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* this is not needed
    FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
    sr.ReadLine();
    */

    // this returns an array of all of the lines you have in your text file 
    //   each line is a new element in the array
    var textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt");

    // here you try to loop the lines in the text file.
    foreach (var Line in textLines)
    {
        // (str, "\n\\s*")
        //string[] dataArray = Regex.Split('n');

        // here you try to split the line on a new line CR + LF (which doesn't exist) so dataArray only has one element
        string[] dataArray = Line.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // this line is useless
        dataArray[0].CompareTo(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

        // this will be true if the current line is the same value as your drop down.
        if (dataArray[0] == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            // this line will work
            textBox1.Text = (dataArray[0]);

            // these will always fail.
            textBox2.Text = (dataArray[1]);
            textBox3.Text = (dataArray[2]);
            textBox4.Text = (dataArray[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

... if you want the text boxes to contain the 4 values from the text files then just do this...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Zeeshan\Downloads\a.txt");
    textBox1.Text = (textLines[0]);
    textBox2.Text = (textLines[1]);
    textBox3.Text = (textLines[2]);
    textBox4.Text = (textLines[3]);
}
```